# How do I add a default value in SQL Server after the table has been created?

Tags: sql-server-2008, default-value, alter-table

So, I've already created my database, but now need to add a default value to a field in a table. I would like to know how to do this without having to drop half my tables and constraints.

I looked online and it said to use this:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ALTER COLUMN ColumnName
SET DEFAULT 1234;
```

I tried using that, however, and I'm getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'." Am I missing something terribly obvious?

Oh, and I guess I should add that the column I'm trying to edit is a foreign key, if that changes anything.

Thanks in advance,
Ellie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- ============================ 
-- Create default constraint
-- ============================ 

ALTER TABLE <schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, table_name>
   ADD CONSTRAINT df_<column_name, sysname, column_name>
   DEFAULT <default_expression, sysname, 0>
   FOR <column_name, sysname, column_name>
GO
```

If you need to add a foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE Products WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Prod_Man] FOREIGN KEY(ManufacturerID)
REFERENCES Manufacturers (ID);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much! I'll accept your answer in about 6 minutes when it finally lets me.

Comment: I agree with the <object, type, default> syntax -- but that's an obscure and thus advanced bit of syntax, and really requires a word or two of explanation for (potentially) newer database users.

Comment: ...whom @HerNameIsEllie clearly is not (saw reply right as mine was posted), but even so.

Comment: I may be a newer database user, but I'm not slow. I hadn't seen that way of writing that stuff out before, but I caught on. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just providing a method (at @Romii's request) for checking whether a default is already defined for the column, using the catalog views instead of the backward compatibility views.

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.default_constraints AS dc
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON dc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
    AND dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE dc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName')
    AND c.name = 'ColumnName'
)
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TableName_ColumnName
    DEFAULT 'whatever' FOR ColumnName;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following query to check whether a default constraint is already defined on the column for that table.

```
SELECT d.definition ,c.name,d.name
FROM sys.default_constraints AS d
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON d.parent_column_id = c.column_id
WHERE d.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TableName]', N'U')
AND c.name = 'ColumnName';
```

Syntax to Add Default Constraint on a column of table.

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
```

Sample Query:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TABLENAME_ColumnName
DEFAULT 1234 FOR ColumnName;
```

Comment: Please use catalog views (sys.tables, sys.columns, sys.default_constraints)... sysobjects and syscolumns are backward compatibility views and should only be used in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: Default constraints are defined in `sys.default_constraints`, and they point to `sys.columns`... I added an answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

To add a default constraint to an existing column, you'd use the `ALTER TABLE` command like so:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName>
 add constraint <ConstraintName>
  default <DefaultValue> for <TargetColumn>
```

An example:

```
ALTER TABLE Pages
 add constraint DF_Pages__Link
  default 'asdf' for Link
```

(My naming convention for default constraints is `DF_ + tablename + __ + column name`)